# idea tomcat8 deployment always 404

Tags: java, servlets, intellij-idea, tomcat8, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to deploy `tomcat8` with `maven` and `web.xml` in Intellij IDEA in Ubuntu 16.04 OS. 
My project referred to as ServletExample. I have following code in my web.xml.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mainServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.mycompany.servlet.MainServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mainServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But always when I'm opening localhost I just become "it works" page or 404(in subURLs).

I've tried to solve the problem.

[image]

After this I can open my servlet in http://localhost:8080/manager.
But I think it's not a correct solving.
**What should I do to open my servlets properly in localhost:8080/?**
If it can help I have such a code in my CATALINA_HOME/conf/tomcat_users.xml

```
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
          version="1.0">
<role rolename="tomcat"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat, manager-gui,    manager-script"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Comment: Which application context are you using for your app?  Is it ROOT, or /something ?  That will need to be included in your URL.

Comment: in all examples that i've seen in internet servlets are opened in localhost:8080/ or localhost:8080/PROJECTNAME.
So i think i want to use / application context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're mixing up two different configuration items.

**1. Your Screenshot from IntelliJ**

This setting means, that your web app will be deployed
to the directory `<Tomcat-Home>/webapps/manager` . Unfortunately, this directory, in most cases, is already used by the "Manager" application which is shipped with Tomcat. In the IntelliJ Run Configuration, you should enter something like "/myApp"

**2. URL mapping in web.xml**

If you write `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` , your application will answer if you address with the URL `http://localhost:8080/myApp/` (corresponding to #1). The directory `<Tomcat-Home>/webapps/myApp` is the root directory of your web app. Don't use `/myApp` in your code.

Comment: yeah, thank you. I've already got it. In all guides was said, that servlet is located in /nameOfProject/... . I did not realize it. And now I actually know, that this is application context rather than nameOfProject

Comment: Lifesaver, finally I can get rid of Netbeans :D